# UITableView not Displaying Data but Already DataSource and Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to make a tableView (within a viewController) that displays a set of data (something I've done before) but this time it isn't displaying the data. I have already declared the viewController as the dataSource and Delegate for the tableView. Here's my viewControllerClass:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource ,          UITableViewDelegate {

    var menuItems = [ "1" , "2" , "3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return menuItems.count
    }

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you add the view controller as the data source and delegate? Where is the table view added to the view and what are its constraints? If you set breakpoints in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt`, are both breakpoints hit?

Comment: Two things... Make sure dataSource and delegate are connected in interface builder or manually set them in your viewDidLoad... Try forcing a tableView.reloadData()

Comment: @keithbhunter I set the view controller as the datasource and delegate in the main.storyboard and I set the breakpoints and both were hit

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are creating the UITableView using xib/Storyboard then datasource and delegates the outlets are connected. Else if you are creating it programmatically then set the delegate and datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You should register the cell inside viewDidLoad() like this:

tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, reuseIdentifier: "cell").
Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

you need IBOutlet for your tableView. From storyboard you need to drag and drop from your table view to your MenuViewController. Then inside your viewDidLoad you need to set datasource and delegate.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
```

Right now your table view has no idea who will provide data. Because of that numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRow is not called. As they are not called, table view doe not know what to display. As table view does not know what to display it does not display anything.